# How am I able to run CRM 2011 on Firefox via Tivoli Access Manager

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, tivoli

We have CRM 2011 installed on Dev server. We can access dev CRM:

```
 1. either through direct url which is like:   
    http://hostname:5555/orgname/main.aspx

 2. or through TAM (Tivoli Access Manager) which has a url like:   
    https://hostname_provided_by_TAM/orgname/main.aspx
```

When we access the CRM through direct url, we can't open it on browsers other than IE but when we access it through TAM, it works fine on IE as well as Mozilla Firefox both. I am wondering how it is possible? One reason that I can think of is that somwhow TAM is making CRM server feel that the request is coming from IE even if it is coming from Firefox. But how?

**Update 1:**
User-Agent string using Mozilla firefox:

```
For direct url: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
For TAM url: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
```

For both the requests, user agent string is same. However, when accessing CRM through direct url only one request (i.e. for main.aspx) goes to the web server and then the error page comes up while using TAM url request for main.aspx returns successfully and CRM page open up.

Comment: What user agent string is TAM sending to CRM? I would hookup Fiddler and see what is different about the request. My guess is that TAM is forcing it to an IE user agent _or_ it is not pointing to the same server (unlikely.)

Comment: Please tell me how can I extract user agent string send by TAM?

Comment: Use Fiddler to watch the network traffic going to your Dev CRM would be my suggestion or ask your TAM administrator if they know another way to get it.

Comment: @Nicknow I have updated the question with user agent strings for both direct url as well as TAM url. Both the strings are taken using firefox.